# Android Cannot Connect To Internet on API < 24

Tags: android

I recently migrated my android app to androidx with targetedSdkVersion of 28.
Now the problem is I'm running some tests on a device running marshmallow (API 23) and any time I try to make an HTTP request I get Connection Error.
I did some digging and added a network_security_config.xml file to my project with the following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But then I found out that the:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

in manifest is only used in api 24+ meaning it's ignored in API 23.

Question is how do I get my HTTP requests working again? I use Androif Fast Networking Library.

These are the permissions I have set in my manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: could you please edit your question with the connection error that you see in the logs for API 23?

Comment: AndroidX is unlikely to have affected this directly. Contact the developer of whatever that library is and see if there are some known conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: There's nothing to add, all I get is Connection Error, Error Code is 0 nothing else.